# Connect sip softphone to local server using the ip address instead of 127.0.0.1

Tags: sip, sip-server, user-presence

I am doing some POC on presence server using SIP servlets. I have connected softphone to the presence server using "127.0.0.1".

Now, I am trying to use the ip(*given by connected wifi router*) instead of 127.0.0.1 to connect to the server but the softphone is not able to register to the server. Gives **SIP 923 No DNS result.** error. The softphone is Zoiper.

I am not able to figure out what exactly is the problem. Probably I may need some extra configurations.

So, how can I connect to local server using my machine ip instead of localhost.

Application setup:
Mobicents presence server on JBoss.

What could be the solution? I guess something like port forwarding!! I have no idea about this, just got some idea by searching for the solution.

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Not related to programming so you probably won't get an answer here.

Comment: Thanks Dijkgraaf.
Actually it is related but yes question does not contain anything in that regards. Can you suggest appropriate forum to post this?

Comment: Possibly http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to make server listen on the IP address instead of loaclhost or 127.0.0.1

We can do this from some configuration file provided by the server where the ip binding is defined.